# Get nested elements on XML (with Lambda) and set to List<Object>

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I have an XML with a List nested and I need all properties inside my class object.

Class:

```
public class Process
{
    public Process()
    {
        Progresses = new List<Progress>();
    }

    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public List<Progress> Progresses { get; set; }
}
public class Progress
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ProgressDate { get; set; }
}
```

XML:

```
 <PROCESSES>
      <Process>
        <Number>8754639647985</Number>
        <Progress>
            <Date>09/11/2013</Date>
            <Text>Lorem lalal asdf</Text>
            <Date>10/11/2015</Date>
            <Text>Lorem lal</Text>
        </Progress>
        <Progress>
            <Date>09/12/2016</Date>
            <Text>Lorem aqwq</Text>
            <Date>10/11/2017</Date>
            <Text>Lorem qw</Text>
         </Progress>
      </Process>
      <Process>
        <Number>1121321321321321</Number>
        <Progress>
            <Date>09/11/2013</Date>
            <Text>Lorem lalal asdf</Text>
            <Date>10/11/2015</Date>
            <Text>Lorem lal</Text>
        </Progress>
        <Progress>
            <Date>09/12/2016</Date>
            <Text>Lorem aqwq</Text>
            <Date>10/11/2017</Date>
            <Text>Lorem qw</Text>
        </Progress>
      </Process>
 </PROCESSES>
```

Until now I have this Linq:

```
var _procs =
    from proc in xml.Root.Elements("Process")
    select new Process()
    {
        Code = (string)proc.Element("Number"),
        Progresses = proc.Elements("Progress")
                           .Select(c => new Progress
                           {
                              Text = (string)c.Element("Text"),
                              ProgressDate = (string)c.Element("Date")
                           }).ToList()
    };
```

But with this, I have one register to each Progress tag, instead of a List of Progresses! My biggest question is, how can I read the XML and set as the Class PROCESS, I need all the PROGRESS tags inside the List on my PROCESS object.

UPDATE:
 With this Linq, I'm getting just the first element of Progress nested nodes.
How can I do that (better if using Lambda)?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be here? You may well just want `from prog in proc.Elements("Progress")` (and remove the `where` clause). That will flatten things though...

Comment: 'Progress' class is inaccesible, because of its visibility. It have to be declared as public class.

Comment: @MaciejLos, the class was just an example. Thanks, it really need to be public.

Comment: @JonSkeet unfortunately I'm getting just the first item of the Progress node. I done like that: `var _procs = from proc in xml.Root.Elements("Process") select new Process()
               {
                   Code = (string)proc.Element("Number"),
                   Progress = proc.Elements("Progress").Select(c => new Progress
                                        {
                                            Text = (string)c.Element("Text"),
                                            ProgressDate = (string)c.Element("Date")      }).ToList()};`

Comment: @IanCampelo: That code looks nothing like the data specified, so it's hard for me to see what's going on...

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, I edited now!

Comment: Well that *would* get more than one `Progress` element... so if you're claiming it doesn't, please edit your question with a [mcve] showing the problem. Something we can copy, paste, compile and run.

Comment: @JonSkeet, fixed! Tell me if you can understand now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, that's not something we can copy, paste, compile, and run. A complete class, that I can literally just copy into a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question `Progress` class have to be declared as `public`.

Another issue is: `Num` is not a member of `Progress` class!

**[EDIT]**

```
var query = xdoc.Descendants("Process")
.Select(x=> new Process
    {
        Code = x.Element("Number").Value,
        Progresses = x.Descendants("Progress")
            .SelectMany((ele, j)=>  ele.Elements("Date").Select((a, i)=>new{Date = a.Value, Index = i+(j*10)}))
            .Join(x.Descendants("Progress").SelectMany((ele, j)=> ele.Elements("Text").Select((a, i)=>new{Text = a.Value, Index = i+(j*10)})),
                    dat => dat.Index,
                    tex => tex.Index,
                    (dat, tex) => new {D = dat, T = tex})
            .Select(jdata=> new Progress
                {
                    //Index = jdata.D.Index,
                    ProgressDate = jdata.D.Date,
                    Text = jdata.T.Text
                }).ToList<Progress>()
    });
```

Above query returns `IEnumerable<Process>` with the list of `Progresses`.

```
Code                Progresses
8754639647985       Lorem lalal asdf    09/11/2013
                    Lorem lal           10/11/2015
                    Lorem aqwq          09/12/2016
                    Lorem qw            10/11/2017
1121321321321321    Lorem lalal asdf    09/11/2013
                    Lorem lal           10/11/2015
                    Lorem aqwq          09/12/2016
                    Lorem qw            10/11/2017
```

Comment: `Progress` is `internal`, which means it can be accessed within the same  assembly by other objects.  So unless `Progress` is in a separate assembly from the code that is using it, I don't think the access modifier is the issue.

Comment: If `Progress` is internal then OK, but we can't know it for sure.

Comment: True, we don't know for sure (though it's a pretty good bet this is all in one assembly).  Based on the OP's question I do not think the access modifier is the issue.  `internal` is the default access modifier for classes and structs.

Comment: @MaciejLos Thanks, but unfortunately I'm getting just the first item of the Progress node, using this approach.

Comment: @IanCampelo, i tested it using LinqPad and i get all items. Are you sure you improved class definition?

Comment: @IanCampelo, OMG, you're right. The reason of that behaviour is that `Progress` node contains more than one `Date` and `Text` subnodes. I'll try to improve the answer ASAP.

Comment: @MaciejLos Yeah! Thanks!

Comment: @IanCampelo, Sorry, i've been busy last few days. Please, check improved solution. Cheers, Maciej

Comment: @MaciejLos Thanks a lot, buddy!